# What does JBoss log "append" do?

Tags: logging, jboss, jboss7.x

I have tried to find information about what is the difference between JBoss log handler append="true" and "false". Could someone explain? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It appends to an existing log file. `append="true"` means that when you start the application and it starts logging it will add lines to the existing log file. `append="false"` means that any existing log file will be deleted, and you'll get a clean log file from this run only.

Comment: Do you really mean that any existing log file will be deleted, or that it will start a new log file? I have configured logger to store latest 20 log files.

Comment: I have the append=true setting, but the server.log is still truncated after the server restart. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

With rolling file appender and append="false" **only the last log file will be deleted** (the one specified with 'name') and only after you restart the app. The rolled ones will remain intact and logger will continue to work and treat your previously backed up logs as if it was never restarted.

BTW, when you add another rolling appender logging to the same file 'on the fly' programmatically (tested with RollingFileAppender, log4j-1.2.17 and same config as the one in log4j.xml). This is where it gets weird - indexes of rolled logs goes crazy. Try it out just to see for yourself.